# What does this circuit do?

Tags: transistors, audio, analog, speakers, multivibrator

If someone could explain how does this circuit operate it would be appreciated.

As far as I can see the "trigger" is a rising edge which is low pass filtered by R10 & C4. I'm not 100% sure about the Q1 & Q4 transistor parts of the circuit. The next part looks like a classic astable multivibrator which chops up the output (?!?) and the last part with an op-amp is a driver for the speaker with some filtering on the output.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a buzzer or beep generator of some sort to me.

Comment: Q1 and Q4 make up a classic high-side power switch.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why does the circuit require this mechanism, the current is low. Also, why use two transistors instead one 1 NPN and connect the multi-vibrator "power" to the emitter?

Comment: The emitter of a NPN BJT is about 0.7V lower than the base, which is why they are rarely used for high-side switching.

Comment: It's just a temporary beep generator. A very silly way to implement it, though. I can't actually understand why the inverting input of IC2 is floating.  
Anyway, C1*(R8+R9) determines the beep duration. When you press the button, current will flow into the base of Q1, that will turn on. Q4 will turn on too, feeding power to the astable you correctly identified. By the way, the trigger is not low pass filtered.

Comment: @next-hack C3 also affects the beep as the value affects the ramp up of voltage the the astable circuit. I think tuning C3 + C1 + C2 would give you control over the sonic qualities of the annoying beep sound. A larger C3 means a softer voltage ramp of the output square wave ( I think)

Comment: Does anyone know the purpose of R6? Is it just to compensate for any leakage current through Q1?

Comment: @immibis In theory, you could remove R6. However, as you said, when Q1 is OFF, there is still a non zero collector current (not to talk that there could be leakage and your transistor could pick up noise from strong sources). Therefore R6 forces the base of Q4 to VDD, when Q1 is off.

Comment: @user34920 yes, you're right.

Comment: As @next-hack mentioned. It wont do much without a feedback connection round the op-amp.

Comment: @Trevor yes obviously you need to hook that up properly

Answer (score 1):

1. in= 22kohm +edge 1-shot
2. out= 220 ohm +edge power 1-shot
3. Astable audio clock 10k out
4. 3 watt audio driver from 9V
5. speaker gets a beep

Basic primitive design